How does chat style promptflow endpoint maintain chat history?
I have created an endpoint for my chat flow using the deploy option in Azure Machine Learning Studio. When I call the endpoint, I receive the expected POST response, but it is not formatted in a chat style.
I would like to understand how the chat history is maintained in this scenario. Specifically, what is the recommended approach for managing chat history when interacting with the endpoint?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.
Steps to Reproduce:

Create a chat flow in Azure Machine Learning Studio.
Deploy the flow as an online endpoint.
Call the endpoint and observe the response format.

Expected Behavior:
The response should be in a chat-friendly format, and there should be a clear method to maintain chat history across interactions.
Actual Behavior:
The response is received in a standard format, lacking the expected chat style, and there is uncertainty regarding chat history management.
Additional Information:

I am using the default settings for the endpoint.
Please provide insights on how to implement chat history tracking, including any necessary parameters or configurations for the requests sent to the endpoint.

